# Deserialize issue with JSON.NET on UWP, using ImmutableList (only Release mode)

Tags: c#, json, serialization, json.net, uwp

I'm experiencing one of these annoying and strange behaviors which differs between Debug and Release mode.
So, we're on UWP 10.0.10586, using JSON.NET 7.0.1

I've a model class that looks like this:

```
[JsonObject]
public class RootObject
{
    [JsonProperty]
    public Profile ProfileInfo { get; set; } = new Profile();

    [JsonProperty]
    public ImmutableList<Info> AdditionalInfo { get; set; } = ImmutableList.Create<Info>();
}
```

Then I try to deserialize a json:

```
var rootObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json);
```

This works perfectly in Debug mode, but doesn't deserialize AdditionalInfo when in Release mode (the list is null).

It also works if I use IEnumerable or IList instead of ImmutableList, but I wonder if there's a reason for this behavior or if is maybe a JSON.NET bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to reflection-activate ImmutableCollection<T>, Json.NET reflects on ImmutableCollection attempting to find the CreateRange method. Since the .NET Native compiler couldn't predict this due to the use of non-trivial reflection, this lookup fails. The error message coming from Json.NET is quite unfortunate because it doesn't tell you that the inability to reflection-find ImmutableCollection.CreateRange is the real problem.

Now that we know this is the problem, we can use the tool at http://dotnet.github.io/native/troubleshooter/type.html to construct a piece of RD.XML that will fix it. The RD.XML that fixes it is:

```
<Type Name="System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableList" Dynamic="Required All" />
```

Comment: What I am not sure about this is where to put the rd.xml. I'm working on a library (dll) project. Should I put the rd.xml to the library project or to the Application project? That's a little bit confusing since all the projects I created has a Default.rd.xml. I'm not sure how these rd.xml files are being used by the application. Is there some documentation that will explain that?

Answer (score 4):

Most likely you are hitting one of the runtime exceptions from .NET Native. To properly diagnose this I'd recommend enabling .NET Native compilation for the DEBUG configuration of your project (Project properties > BUILD > Enable .Net Native checkbox). Then, set your debugger to stop on first chance exceptions.

Now when you run you'll probably see a MissingMetadataException or somethign about serialization but because you're in DEBUG you'll get decent exception strings. If you can move to Update 1, the messages are a bit better. Most likely you'll need to add something to your Default.rd.xml file.

Comment: Ok this helped me to get at least an exception instead of a silent change of behavior. Though the exception is a "JsonSerializerException" - Unable to find a constructor to use for type ImmutableList<Info>

Just to be clear:
result in Debug: http://i.imgur.com/8JriPfP.png
resuit in Debug with .NET Native: http://i.imgur.com/uGT7OEt.png

Any tip about what I should add to Default.rx.xml if that is the issue?

Answer (score 1):

We had a similar problem, but the .rd.xml trick did not fix it. The code deserializes the JSON to a dynamic object, and works great in Debug mode, and worked in Release mode prior to updating UWP to 10.0.15138.  But now it crashes in Release mode.

Here was the line before the fix (does not work):

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(rpcStatus);
```

The fix is to specify ExpandoObject as the type for Newtonsoft to deserialize to, like so (does work):

```
dynamic obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ExpandoObject>(rpcStatus);
```